# HTML5 application Cache for pdf files, for static single page app

Tags: html, single-page-application

I have a single page application and I created a main.appache file which is referred to HTML using 

the main.appache has a pdf links. When loading the page will the pdf file be cached automatically? 
As I have to first be online and open the pdf file then when I go offline I am able to view it. But is there a way we can do it while loading the single page application without going online to retrieve the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When loading the page will the pdf file be cached automatically?

Yes, anything included in the manifest will be downloaded the first time a page that references the manifest is loaded.

> But is there a way we can do it while loading the single page application without going online to retrieve the pdf file.

No, you're always going to have to be online to retrieve the PDF for the first time. Subsequent visits will use the cached version.